# I got a postgresql db that works but on host/admin (in the browser) i get a no such table : auth_user

Tags: python, django, django-admin

i'm using django with my postgresql database.

When i use manage.py makemigrations and migrate everything works fine. I can create objects in the shell and save them.

However when i try to get to the admin page on my browser and log in as a superuser, i get a no such table : auth_user error

I saw this in the error page : "Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 450
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python"

It seems like the admin page is using a sqlite3 db oO

I didn't find a solution on the internet yet

Here is my solution.py :

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'basic.apps.BasicConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lifelines.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lifelines.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME':'******',
    'USER':'*******',
    'PASSWORD':'*******',
    'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
    'PORT':'5432',
}
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: can you show your settings.py file?

Comment: I edited the post with my settings.py file

Comment: I see that you use Django 1.6, if its true, did you use this command `python manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: I did a pip upgrade to use makemigrations command so now syncdb doesn't work, i use migrate instead

Comment: are you using the dev server ?

Comment: did you ever login in admin page in this project?

Comment: No i didn't manage to access the dev server from my browser. The thing i want to do is show the admin page to my coworker to show him the database tables so i have to be able to connect to admin  from another computer

Comment: Alright i managed to make it work by allowing the host to my domain's name and running the server. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i managed to use the dev server by putting my domain's name in "ALLOWED_HOST" and running the server on port 8000. Thanks for your help people